# How to include image to header (as well as content) in CSS?

Tags: css

On [my website](http://www.wychelmstudios.com/contact/) I have included a background (on the contact page). However when I put in the background it does not cover the header. It has done it on the main page but not on the contact page? I have tried to use

```
#siteWrapper{
  background-image: url("http://static.squarespace.com/static/545d45afe4b08eea0ac65e7a/t/54612b8ae4b0ca233d43bdee/1415654282657/Website%20Background%20Trees.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

So here, it puts the background in and it fits it to the screen with `background-size: 100%;` but this has only put it over the content. I have tried to put the background on the body however that has put it behind the content. So the main goal is to try and include the background into the header as well as the content (like the home page). - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#site{
  background-image: url("http://static.squarespace.com/static/545d45afe4b08eea0ac65e7a/t/54612b8ae4b0ca233d43bdee/1415654282657/Website%20Background%20Trees.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Remove header from:

```
body.transparent-header:not(.has-banner-image) #header {
    background-color: #100806;
    position: relative;
} //site.css line 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background image on the #site element instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1:

You're using `position: relative` for your header on your Contact page, but `absolute` on your main page.

Use this CSS for all page but homepage:

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: none;
}
#siteWrapper {
    padding-top: 106px; /* leave some space for header */
}
```

### Solution #2:

Move your background image on `#site`, and remove black backgrounds:

```
#site {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("http://static.squarespace.com/static/545d45afe4b08eea0ac65e7a/t/54612b8ae4b0ca233d43bdee/1415654282657/Website%20Background%20Trees.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
header,
#siteWrapper {
    background: none;
}
```

---

Sidenotes:

Be careful, the `Submit` button may appears exactly where there's a lightning area in your background image, making it unreadable:

[image]

Comment: None of these have worked I am afraid (as well as the other solutions). I have tried to play around with it for a bit and no luck.

Comment: @BittenFleax I tried it with success on your website.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for the note. When I put content above it, it will move it down out of the light. Thanks though. So do I just remove the code the code and put your solution 2 in? Because when I tried that I did not have success?

Comment: I will have to postpone this until later because I am not available until for another 5 hours or so. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

CSS changes:

//Change this #site css to

```
    #site {
 background: url("http://static.squarespace.com/static/545d45afe4b08eea0ac65e7a/t/54612b8ae4b0ca233d43bdee/1415654282657/Website%20Background%20Trees.png") repeat scroll 0 0 / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
position: relative;
```

}

//Remove this below class css

```
.collection-545e428fe4b0f79db6910e91 #siteWrapper {
background-image: url("http://static.squarespace.com/static/545d45afe4b08eea0ac65e7a/t/54612b8ae4b0ca233d43bdee/1415654282657/Website%20Background%20Trees.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
```

}

//remover background-color css in below two section "background-color: #100806"

## siteWrapper{background-color: #100806;}

body.transparent-header:not(.has-banner-image) #header{  background-color: #100806;}
[image]

Comment: Hmm has not worked. I think it is `#site` because no matter what I do nothing changes. Is it called something different because I looked and could not find anything.

Comment: Hmm. It has not worked? Do I just put the `siteWrapper{background-color: #100806;}` and the `body.transparent-header:not(.has-banner-image) #header{ background-color: #100806;}` as 2 different lines below the code that you said to put?